# How to configure HSQLDB 2.2.5 in Maven POM?

Tags: maven, hsqldb, pom.xml

I am unable to find HSQLDB-2.2.5 POM at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hsqldb/hsqldb. Can anyone help how maven POM can be set to work with HSALDB-2.2.5 version?

Answer (score 8):

maybe it has not been uploaded yet? There appears to be a 2.2.4 here:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.2.4/

In order to reference it as a dependency in you pom.xml, i guess you'll have to add something like this to your dependencies block

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried the above instead of 2.2.4 I used 2.2.5, I am getting a jar not found error. I really would not want to change the DB version

Comment: so if you know that version exists, you can add it to your local repository and also to your shared repository by using mvn install-file or mvn deploy-file.

Comment: The current version, as of Feb 2013, is hsqldb 2.2.9.    Things have apparently changed over time, and there's no authoritative source anywhere clarifying all the conflicts.  If there were such a document, it would say, "ignore everything you read on the internet that references `hsqldb` as the org name for use within maven for hsqldb.  The org is now `org.hsqldb`.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me today (Feb 28, 2014). Older versions don't seem to work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```